# Can't insert a NOT NULL column with a default value NULL

Tags: sqlite

```
ALTER TABLE informations 
    ADD id INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL;
```

> Runtime error: Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL

I tried to insert a column but it keeps saying this error, I need some help I tried default it worked but the id can't be changed by itself

Comment: So If the value can not be null, and you don't enter a value, the database would try to use null as default, that it isn't allowed, so it's very sensible to deny you that change

Comment: Provide a default value. For not-null integer, 0 (zero) wouldn't be too surprising. Just make sure it is treated as illegal/invalid id for the rest of the app.

Comment: You need to make this a 3 step process 1) add the column allowing nulls 2) update the column for any existing rows with valid values 3) alter the column to not null

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT use a default value of NULL (implied in your example) when ALTERing the table and ADDing a COLUMN if the NOT NULL constraint is specified, as per:-

> If a NOT NULL constraint is specified, then the column **must have a default value other than NULL**.

from ***4. ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN*** https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

e.g. you could use:-

```
ALTER TABLE informations 
ADD id INTEGER IDENTITY NOT NULL DEFAULT -1;
```

That is there will be an expectation, when actually altering the table, that all existing rows in the table will have a value applied for the added column and thus that it cannot be NULL as that would then conflict with the NOT NULL constraint. This even if the table is empty when altering it.